# python read a file to make it sorted but from many different separators

Tags: python, split

My need is to get a log build like :

```
2022-08-22 - something WARN - data1 = 6.3 something| data2 = 7 something | data3 = 8 units
```

And to at very end have a Json output within

```
'field1':'2022-08-22','field2':'something','data1':'6.3','data2':'7','data3':'8'
```

So I need to manage auto naming field1 & field2 keynames & to manage all of "WARN",'-','=','|' as distinct separators

I tried few codes around more or less similar solutions to

```
split_string = sample_string.split(',|\|=')  # just interprets the ',' char only
```

as first step (current question) to get separators working but I already failed on that part

isn't split the good function/solution to get it  using python 2.7 without pandas module (not allowed in my company).

Comment: How do you tell when `-` is a separator and when it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split` uses its parameter literally.  It doesn't look for "one of", it looks for exactly the string you pass.   So, do it in steps.  First, `split(' - ')`.  That gives you the date, the pre-WARN string, and a final field with the data.

```
s = "2022-08-22 - something WARN - data1 = 6.3 something| data2 = 7 something | data3 = 8 units"

p1 = s.split(' - ')
print(p1)
p2 = p1[2].split('|')
print(p2)

data = {}
data['field1'] = p1[0]
data['field2'] = p1[1].strip().split()[0]

for part in p2:
    p3 = part.strip().split('=')
    data[p3[0]] = p3[1].strip()

print(data)
```

Output:

```
['2022-08-22', 'something WARN', 'data1 = 6.3 something| data2 = 7 something | data3 = 8 units']
['data1 = 6.3 something', ' data2 = 7 something ', ' data3 = 8 units']
{'field1': '2022-08-22', 'field2': 'something', 'data1 ': '6.3 something', 'data2 ': '7 something', 'data3 ': '8 units'}
```